# i18n Hello world

Tags: internationalization

I'm trying to write a simple Hello world program in i18n form, using C...
Can someone please help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hum, let's try to make some sense out of this question :)
If you use C and have gettext available, you can do:

```
#include <libintl.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
  setlocale (LC_ALL, "");
  bindtextdomain ("hello", "/usr/share/locale");
  textdomain ("hello");
  printf (gettext ("Hello, world!\n"));
  exit (0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [GNU Hello World](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/) program. It demonstrates a lot of good programming principles, including internationalization. From the `hello` man page:

> GNU Gettext (see Introduction) is used for internationalization support. Hello's greeting has been translated into many languages.